# Why doesn't GLib's GValue system include string to number transformations?

Tags: type-conversion, glib

The GValue system in GLib includes standard type transformations using GType descriptors (in fact the [GValue reference page](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/gobject-Generic-values.html) includes some sample code that transforms a value from int to string).

However, as one can also see from the [gvaluetransform source code](http://glib2.0.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.25.8-1ubuntu1/gvaluetransform_8c-source.html), transformations from string to numeric values are not included by default. I suppose that parsing strings to integers is a quite commonly used feature. Is there a specific reason we need to manually supply transformation functions for string parsing (portability perhaps)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was left out because there's no way to report or handle errors in GValue transformations.